# Como Crear estructura de XML con PHP DOMDocummnet

Tags: php, xml

Tengo la siguiente estructura de un XML. ¿Cómo sería la creación de dicho XML usando PHP? He revisado documentacion de `DOMDocument`, pero ando algo perdido con la creación de `Namespaces` y sus atributos, agradecería alguna orientanción.

Aqui está la estructura:

```
<prefix:Documment xmlns:prefix="http://example.com" `xmlns:xs="http://example.com" xmlns:xsi="http://example.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com http://example.com" Version="3.3"/>`
<prefix:data1 value1="123" value2="123"/>
<prefix:data2 value1="123" value2="123"/>
 <prefix:Concepts>
     <prefix:Concept value1="123" value2="123"/>
      <prefix:other>
        <prefix:other2>
           <prefix:other2 value1="123" value2="123"/>                   
        </prefix:other2>                              
      </prefix:other>
     </prefix:Concept>
 <prefix:Concepts>
</prefix:Documment>
```