# ¿Cómo puedo crear un XML en PHP?

Tags: php, xml, dom

Buen día Compañeros,

Tengo la necesidad de poder crear un XML a partir de data que obtengo de una base de datos MySQL, actualmente tengo un template el cual modifico agregando o quitando nodos, sin embargo hace poco tuve la experiencia de crear directamente el árbol completo desde Ruby con la librería Nokogiri, la cual me dejó completo control sobre el DOM, con lo cual pude sentir la libertad de generar el XML conforme yo lo requería sin tener que estar amarrado al template, ya que se hizo de forma dinámica, existe algo similar en PHP? Algo que me ayude a tener control total sobre los nodos, sus atributos y valores, sobre los namespaces? He estado buscando sin mucho resultado que ahonde en el tema, inclusive acá he encontrado preguntas ([Como Crear estructura de XML con PHP DOMDocummnet](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130958/como-crear-estructura-de-xml-con-php-domdocummnet)) sin respuestas, de antemano les agradezco por el apoyo.

Saludos cordiales

Comment: Hay varias preguntas/respuestas en el sitio en inglés que muestran ejemplos de cómo volcar los resultados de la consulta en un XML. [Por ejemplo esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112417/5587982), pero ignora las funciones relativas a mysql, pues son obsoletas. [O bien esta que usa PDO para manejo de la base de datos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15982616/5587982). Se trata de organizar los nodos de tu XML y recorrer los resultados escribiendo cada dato adecuadamente. MySQL tiene también funciones para volcar el resultado directamente en un XML, pero no parece ser lo que quieres.

Comment: He buscado pero ninguna satisface mis necesidades o por lo menos son muy escuetas a lo que ando buscando, no entiendo la mala calificación

Comment: El voto negativo que te han dado ha sido posiblemente a que la pregunta en realidad no se adapta al formato del sitio, entre otras cosas porque no muestras ningún intento de código basado en lo que has investigado. Realmente no hay punto de partida para poder ayudarte mejor, mi idea de proporcionar algunos enlaces era para que te decidas por el ejemplo que mejor te parezca y empieces con algo de código. A partir de ahí es más fácil ir ajustando/corrigiendo una respuestas con ayuda de esta comunidad. En cuanto mejores la pregunta quizá quien votó negativo retire ese voto y lo cambie por un +.